# How to reset vote count in bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

I am using Bugzilla 3.6.3. I would like to reset the vote count for a bug back to zero if the status is changed to UNCONFIRMED. What perl file and method do I do this in and how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to do this, both involving hooks:

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/api/Bugzilla/Extension.html

There are examples of how to use the hooks in `extensions/Example/Extension.pm`.

The way I would do this would be to use the `bug_end_of_update` hook.

There's code in `extensions/Example/Extension.pm` that is almost exactly what you want. If one of the changes is to `bug_status` and the new value is `UNCONFIRMED`, then directly manipulate the database to reset the number of votes to 0, i.e. `DELETE FROM bugs WHERE bug_id = ?`

The other way to do this would be to use `object_end_of_update`, which is basically the same as `bug_end_of_update`, but you'd have to check that the object is a `Bugzilla::Bug`.